# XML elements send to Spring Boot REST API is not mapped to POJO if xml element naming convention is different to POJO attribute naming convention

Tags: xml, rest, web-services, spring-boot, jaxb

When I'm sending XML payload to REST controller is not mapped as expected. My implementation has been done by using Spring Boot. I have generated the POJOs based on the XSD file using JaxB. XML elements are mapped only if they follow the same naming convention followed in POJO.

```
<Declaration xmlns:p="My_Common_Types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="MY_Schema.xsd">
    <ID>ID</ID>
    <Regime>REG</Regime>
</Declaration>
```

Generated Code Using JAXB is as follows,

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "id",
        "regime"
    })
    @XmlRootElement(name = "Declaration")
    public class Declaration {

        @XmlElement(name = "ID")
        protected String id;

        @XmlElement(name = "Regime")
        protected String regime;

        public String getID() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setID(String value) {
            this.id = value;
        }

        public String getRegime() {
            return regime;
        }

        public void setRegime(String value) {
            this.regime = value;
        }
    }
```

Rest Controller is as follows,

```
    @RestController
    public class XMLConsumerController {

        @PostMapping("/xmlPayload")
        public void decodeXML(@RequestBody Declaration xmlPayLoad) {

        }
    }
```

pom.xml dependencies are as follows,

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Really appreciate if someone can help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the **jackson-dataformat-xml** dependency and will work.

Update:

Used your pasted xml, via Postman. The body is sent as text/xml. My dependencies as below:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And it works fine

Update 2:

From the message in the error response, it looks that it expects namespace for the Declaration, even I do not see it in the class you posted. Probably there is a namespace specified in package-info.java.

Ok try with this body for the request:

```
<p:Declaration xmlns:p="My_Common_Types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="MY_Schema.xsd">
    <ID>ID</ID>
    <Regime>REG</Regime>
</p:Declaration>
```

It may still fail, but definitely will not complain about Declaration. If it does about the ID or Regime then add the 'p' prefix in the payload and repeat.

Comment: after removing the dependency, it gives a bad request (status code 400)

Comment: hm bad request? that is strange. I have used what you posted and sent the xml described. Only difference might be in the pom. I ll update in the response. Please try it and let me know

Comment: i have tried with your dependencies as well. But it didn't work. same thing happened. And I am using the same mechanism (Postman) to send the payload.

Comment: And what happens if your xml follows the naming conventions? it is strange that it sees it as a bad request.

Comment: Does it give you extra info? why is it a bad request? did you double check the xml sent?

Comment: After removing the dependency, it gives the same bad request even after following the naming conventions. Yes I have double checked the xml as well.

Comment: postman would give you status, error, exception, message and path. What is there on exception and message?

Comment: Error I got - { "timestamp": 1520209977886, "status": 400, "error": "Bad Request", "exception": "org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException", "message": "Could not unmarshal to [class com.webservice.demo.services.Declaration]: unexpected element (uri:\"\", local:\"Declaration\"). Expected elements are <{My_Common_Types}Declaration>; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:\"\", local:\"Declaration\"). Expected elements are <{My_Common_Types}Declaration>", "path": "/xmlPayload" }

Comment: No this time it worked. In my case i can't change the xml file. it should be same to which I have provided. However with your suggestion I just made a tiny change to my POJO. I have added namespace = "" to @XmlRootElement then it worked. 
Thanks a lot

Comment: @mart, what did you do for getting it to work? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @Ayan the question was made by imoremada. What is your problem? You also get a bad request? can you copy the error response details?

Comment: I either get a 400 or null. here is the minimal version I got:https://github.com/ayan4c/test-jaxb

Comment: @Ayan can you please also copy the request body you post?

Comment: when I send request with

<User><name>FirstName</name><company>XYZ</company></User>
it is accepted in service and able to access values.

When I send request with

<User><Name>FirstName</Name><Company>XYZ</Company></User>
, it is accepted but all the values are null

Comment: @Ayan remove the jackson-dataformat-xml from your pom (lines 68 to 71) and will work. just tested it